# Does anyone know of any other hidden abilities of civilization leaders?

Tags: civilization-5

The only ability which is listed anywhere for Alexander (Greece), other than the unique units, is that influence over city states is decreased at half rate and increased at double rate.

However, I've recently learned that additionally, Greek units cannot trespass on the territory of neutral city-states - here's an image showing the description of this "trait" (this was taken at the beginning of the game, no special social policies and I just encountered this city-state):

[image: a screenshot showing that Alexander cannot trespass]

Does anyone know of any other, "hidden" traits, or can provide a link to anywhere which lists them?

Comment: Not "hidden" exactly, but note that Arabia's special trait is listed in the manual as "+$2/trade route", but in the game it is "+$1/trade route, and double oil resources".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This page](http://www.quartertothree.com/game-talk/showthread.php?p=2395093) has a number of interesting tidbits that aren't easily discoverable, including the one you mentioned above about Greece.  Nothing else about civ leader specific abilities though.

> You can skip the intro movie by
>   hitting Escape; however, the game
>   loads data in the background while the
>   movie is playing, and therefore the
>   movie won't actually stop until
>   background loading is complete.
>
> To access predefined maps, such as the
>   Mesopotamia map that was part of some
>   special editions, choose Mods and then
>   Single Player. You can now select
>   among all installed maps by clicking
>   on the map button.
>
> To show the movement range of a
>   selected unit and the path it would
>   take when ordered to move, either
>   press "M" or hold down the right mouse
>   button while moving the mouse cursor
>   over the map.
>
> The maximum radius within which a city
>   can allocate workers is three hexagons
>   in any direction.
>
> Marble speeds production of all
>   wonders by 25% in the city that works
>   the quarry.
>
> Greece has the special ability that
>   moving units through the territory of
>   city states never degrades influence
>   with them.
>
> Railroads not only give the usual gold
>   & movement bonuses for roads, but also
>   +50% production for cities connected to the capital. Harbors act as
>   railroad connections as soon as the
>   technology is available. The exact
>   movement bonuses for roads & railroads
>   are unknown.
>
> Units count towards a supply limit
>   defined by your cities and population,
>   shown on the military overview. The
>   exact effect of reaching that limit is
>   unknown.
>
> Units have a maintenance cost (aka
>   upkeep) in gold which depends on your
>   total number of units, and is
>   summarized in the economic overview.
>   The actual formula for unit
>   maintenance is as yet unknown, and may
>   or may not be related to the unit
>   supply limit.
>
> If you have no gold left and are
>   running a deficit in excess of 5 GP
>   per turn, units will begin to be
>   forcibly disbanded to save on
>   maintenance costs.
>
> Razing a city takes one turn per
>   population point, and begins only
>   after you end your turn. So if you
>   choose to raze a conquered city, you
>   can still enter the city screen and
>   cancel the razing. The city will then
>   be annexed -- you cannot turn it into
>   a puppet state anymore.
>
> Pacts of Cooperation make the AI
>   friendlier and more receptive to other
>   deals. Pacts of Secrecy against
>   another player do the same but with
>   the added condition that neither
>   player must cooperate with the target
>   player.
>
> Being allied with a city state grants
>   you an automatic view of all tiles
>   they can see. There is no other form
>   of map trading; the only way to
>   explore a major civilization's
>   territory is to sign Open Borders and
>   scout it with your units.
>
> The manual once mentions that hotkeys
>   are documented in the readme file, but
>   they are actually listed in the manual
>   itself on page 207. You should still
>   have a look at the readme file ("Read
>   Me .pdf" in your Civ5
>   installation folder) as it has some
>   other useful information, such as the
>   location of the editable Civ5
>   initialization file.
>
> Looking for the real-time clock?
>   Remember this is a Steam game -- if
>   you have the misleadingly named "Steam
>   Community In-Game" enabled in your
>   Steam settings, you can simply hit
>   Shift+Tab and get a big fat clock in
>   the top-left corner, along with other
>   Steam UI.

Answer (score 5):

Even though the description of the trait doesn't mention it, Hiawatha's "The Great Warpath" grants you all the benefits of railroads in all forests inside your borders as soon as you have researched Railroad. This includes a production bonus to connected cities and faster movement.

Answer (score 0):

Siam also has a hidden ability. As well as getting the bonus food, faith, and culture from friendly city states, any units that you get will have experience. I think it's 10xp, but I'm not sure